# Calculating Mean and Percent

Tags: sas

I am using the NHANES 2017-2018 dataset and I am confused how to write the code to answer these 2 questions.

1. /* Calculate the Mean percent of calories consumed attributed to saturated fat among adults using these conversions*/
   /* 1gm FAT=9 Calories, 1gm Carb=4 calories, 1gm Protein=4 calories, 1gm SATFAT=9 calories*/
2. /*. 2. Excluding those with missing data, what percent of American adults (18 and older) from the
   NHANES sample follow the USDA recommendations that they should consume less than 10% of
   their Calories from Saturated Fat?*/

This is what I wrote so far at the top of my code

```
data CALORIES;
set LAB.NHANES;

TOT_CAL=(FAT1*9)+(PROTEIN*4)+(CARB1*4);
TOT_SAT=(SATFAT*9)/(TOT_CAL);

if TOT_SAT=. then TOT_SAT_10=3;
else if TOT_SAT>.10 then TOT_SAT_10=1;
else if TOT_SAT le .10 then TOT_SAT_10=2;
RUN;
```